# Do entities inherit relationships aswell? or only attributes

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

Say I have a entity `Employee` and a `Employee` has a `emergency contact` entity.

If I then had a entity, `doctor` that inherited from `Employee`, **would the `doctor` entity have a relationship with the `emergency contact` entity?**

Or does the doctor only inherit the attributes from the `Employee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will carry the relationships. Every Doctor is also an Employee because of inheritance.

Comment: So the doctor will also have a relation with the emergency contact entity?

Comment: yes, because its base class is Employee. Therefore, Every property of Employee is inherited by Doctor. EmergencyContact is also an property, called Navigation property.